# Display all available users on a given day

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join

I want to display all available users (user type: employee) on a given schedule date. They are not available if they are scheduled both day (PM/AM)

Here are my following tables:

**User Types**

```
TypeID     TypeName
1          Admin
2          Employee
```

**Users**

```
UserID     TypeID     Name
1          1          Admin 1
2          2          Employee 1
3          2          Employee 2
4          1          Admin 2
5          2          Employee 3
6          2          Employee 4
7          2          Employee 5
```

**Schedule**

```
SchedID   UserID      SchedDate     Day (PM/AM)
1         2           8/27/2013     PM
2         2           8/27/2013     AM
3         3           8/27/2013     AM
4         5           8/27/2013     PM
5         6           8/27/2013     AM
```

**Expected Result** (WHERE SchedDate='8/27/2013')

```
UserID    Name
3         Employee 2
5         Employee 3
6         Employee 4
7         Employee 5
```

This is my current SQL statement:

```
SELECT Users.UserID, Users.Name FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Schedule ON Schedule.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE Users.TypeID = 5
```

Comment: Trying to understand the logic, why is UserID 3 not included in the expected result?

Comment: @Gidil . . . According to the logic in the text, UserId 3 should be returned.  It is equivalent to ID 7 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ooops. Forgot to add :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's phrase this a little differently.  A user is unavailable if the user has both AM and PM scheduled for the `DAY` column.  Otherwise, the user is available.

Given that there are only two values in that column, the following query does the filtering you want:

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.Name
FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Schedule s
     ON s.UserID = u.UserID and
        s.ScheduleDate = '2013-08-27'
WHERE u.TypeID = 5
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.Name
HAVING COUNT(distinct s.day) < 2;
```

If you know the values are never repeated, then you can change the `having` clause to:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2;
```

This is a bit of a trick.  When there is no match in the schedule table at all, the counts will return `0` (in the first case) or `1` (in the second case).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USERS.USERID, 
       USERS.NAME 
FROM   USERS 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SCHEDID 
                   FROM   SCHEDULE 
                   WHERE  SCHEDULE.USERID = USERS.USERID 
                          AND DAY = 'AM') 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SCHEDID 
                       FROM   SCHEDULE 
                       WHERE  SCHEDULE.USERID = USERS.USERID 
                              AND DAY = 'PM')
```

Comment: I think USERIDs 5 and 6 will not be returned with your query.

Comment: Your query is almost correct. You just need to use "OR NOT EXISTS" rather than "AND NOT EXISTS" so that Users 5 and 6 are returned because they don't have 'AM' OR they don't have 'PM'

Comment: Just left sone thinking to abram (middle "AND" shd be "OR")